# Want to display SMB share as folder instead of drive

Tags: mount, smb, nas

What I'm trying to do is mount an SMB share to a user directory created for it. Eventually, I want to replace a Mac's Pictures directory with the contents of a NAS. I want it to look to the user as if she is just navigating her Pictures directory as she does when it is local storage, but it has instead the super large capacity of a mounted directory from a NAS. The user is not well versed in navigating network drives.

- I created a test directory: `mkdir ~/SMB_Test`
- I mounted the NAS share: `mount_smbfs //user_on_NAS:passwd_on_NAS@192.168.122.17/Home ~/SMB_Test/`

This works. It just doesn't look exactly the way I want for the user. Is what I want achievable?

- I want it to look like a folder, not a drive.
- I want it to keep the name of the mount point, SMB_Test, but it assumes the name Home, taken from the NAS.

An SMB share to Ubuntu appears the way I want. Can OSX do the same?

Comment: I *think* the name "Home" is not coming from the Mac, rather it is a share name published by your NAS. The Mac will just mount that share as presented by the server, so there may be some less well documented settings that you need to adjust on your NAS.

Comment: What about using a Symbolic link?

Comment: Yes, the name Home comes from the NAS. However, Ubuntu does what I want, so some clients do it. I'm hoping someone is aware of a setting I can employ on the Mac.

That symbolic link idea is pretty cool. I've never used those. I'll try it.

Comment: Even if it looks like a folder on the boot drive, it can't behave like one. Anything dragged to it is going to have to copy rather than move [Unless you intervene & hold Cmd]

Comment: I'm fine with that. It will be good enough.

Comment: The symbolic link is a nice option. I can specify the name I want. However, the icon still looks like a drive. The requirement I want to support is for the user to see a folder in the finder. I don't see a way to change the preview (icon) for a symbolic link.